# New construction, who is responsible for water drainage?

Tags: drain

We moved into our new construction and opted to do the landscaping at a later time. I have already put downspouts and extensions to get the water 20 ft away from the house. However, the way the land lays, water ponds up around our basement pretty bad. Is this a contractor issue or would it have been landscaping?

Answer (score 3):

Any contractor worth his salt would make sure that the site was graded to always slope away from the house. It’s part of keeping the house dry and I don’t think this aspect of the work falls under the category of landscaping. He should be responsible for correcting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a foundation drainage system is required by the builder of the house. The Code says, “Drains shall be provided around concrete or masonry foundations that retain earth and enclose habitable space below grade.” (See ICC R405.1.)

There is one exception to that, and that is if you have, “well draining Grade 1 soils,” (basically rock and sand) which I doubt you have.